# How to access JSON object in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have used Mongodb with Php I want to retrive document from mongo collections with ajax call, so I have tried follwing way but i am strugle with access json object in jquery..
Jquery CODE

```
$('select[name=trendsName]').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:'getTrendsFullInfo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {trendsName: $(this).val(), collectionName:'trends_collection'},

        success: function(res){
             for(var i = 0; i < res.trendsArr['LSM'].length; i++){
                $('.resArea').append(res.trendsArr['LSM'][i]);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

getTrendsFullInfo.php

```
$finalResultArr = array();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['trendsName']) && isset($_REQUEST['collectionName'])):
        $status = "Sucessfully Retrived From ".$_REQUEST['collectionName']." Record";
        $finalResultArr['LSM'] = array(
                                    '10-12' => 237,
                                    '13-15' => 565,
                                    '16-18' => 825);
        $outputArr = array('status'=>$status, 'trendsArr'=>$finalResultArr);

        echo json_encode($outputArr);   
    endif;
```

How to access trendsArr object in jquery?

Comment: Run the browser debugger (F12) set a breakpoint on the line `for(var i = 0; i < res.trendsArr['LSM'].length; i++){` and then use the debugger to look at the data returned from PHP in the `res` variable

Comment: `console.log(res.trendsArr)` chk this first,

Comment: put `console.write(res);` before the `for` loop and post what you see.

Comment: How do you initialize `$finalResultArr` ? It should be initialised as `$finalResultArr = [];` before usage to get a valid result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you can't use `.length` for objects ,it will show you `undefined` only .So use `for in` because you don't know what your object key is

```
$('select[name=trendsName]').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:'getTrendsFullInfo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {trendsName: $(this).val(), collectionName:'trends_collection'},

        success: function(res){
             for(var i in res.trendsArr['LSM']){
                console.log(" Key => "+ i +" && Value => "+ res.trendsArr['LSM'][i]);
                $('.resArea').append(res.trendsArr['LSM'][i]);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: it has worked but how to get key and value? `Array
(
    [10-12] => 235
    [13-15] => 585
    [16-18] => 525
)` i want 10-12 and that value 235

Comment: console `i` that will be key